# Parsing custom string

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working in a alphabet soup and i need to parse strings like this:

```
A1 A10

A10 B14

C1 C14

C14 C8
```

where the letters can be from A to T and numbers from 1 to 20.

My idea in general was to get something like this (with A1 A10)

```
string[0] = "A"
string[1]= "1"
string[4] = "A"
string[5] = "10"
```

maybe any ideas or code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse"? What information are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Why are you skipping indices? I'd use a `dictionary`

Comment: Try a regex. Something along the lines of /[A-T](2 digits)/ to give you a rough idea. Your current solution is weak because it first assumes that each line is a complete string and doesn't factor in all digit possibilities.

Comment: i already write a tons of ideas. First making a list and join the spliting , i get something like ['A1','A10'] but i cannot access to A or 1. After maybe using the string and using their access but i get confused to check EX my string can be
A1 A10
B14 B10

How i can check if after the letter , have 2 or 1 number?

@jonrsharpe, really shame of you , do you think if i didn't have writte any code i came here to ask? This forum is my last option to get help. If you don't plant to help please skip this.

Comment: NOTE: I can't use regex.. for the moment in my class we don't see that..

Comment: *"i already write a tons of ideas"* - good! Why not mention some of them in your question? *"do you think if i didn't have writte any code i came here to ask?"* - lots of people do, unfortunately. So where is that code, and what precisely is the problem with it? *"If you don't plant to help please skip this"* - no dice, sorry. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple

Use the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=.split#str.split) function transform your alphabet soup, then split the single elements further by directly accessing them.

For example:

```
text = '''
A1 A10
A10 B14
C1 C14
C14 C8
'''

for t in text.split():
    print(
        {t[0]: t[1:]}
    )
```

prints:

```
{'A': '1'}
{'A': '10'}
{'A': '10'}
{'B': '14'}
{'C': '1'}
{'C': '14'}
{'C': '14'}
{'C': '8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , i solve this (For the moment is working i guess!), maybe isn't the best way to do it , but is the only way i can do with my knowledge. any better idea will be really accepted ! (Please , if you're reading this because you need something like this , i only posted this because is the only way how i know to do it , maybe someone wish to post a better code down!)

```
fila = preguntar_coordenadas[0]
desde = int(preguntar_coordenadas[1])
if preguntar_coordenadas[2].isdigit():
    desde = int("{0}   {1}".format(preguntar_coordenadas[1],preguntar_coordenadas[2]))
if preguntar_coordenadas[3].isalpha():
    columna = preguntar_coordenadas[3]
    if len(preguntar_coordenadas) == 5:
        hasta = int(preguntar_coordenadas[4])
    else:
        hasta = int("{0}{1}".format(preguntar_coordenadas[4],preguntar_coordenadas[5]))
 else:
columna = preguntar_coordenadas[4]
if len(preguntar_coordenadas) == 6:
    hasta = int(preguntar_coordenadas[5])
else:
    hasta = int("{0}{1}".format(preguntar_coordenadas[5],preguntar_coordenadas[6]))
 #DEBUG
 print "fila {0} ; columna {1} ; desde {2} ; hasta {3}".format(fila,columna,desde,hasta)
```

The idea base was receive a string "A[1-20] B[1-20]" A and B can be any letter from A to T, store each word splitted to access it:
Ex: "A14 B16"

> [0] = "A"
>
> [1] = "14"
>
> [2] = "B"
>
> [3] = "16"

Sorry if I expressed myself incorrectly and no one understood me!

Comment: 3 years later, yes, 3 years, i realized this can be done easily with regex, content far away for me on that time.